# Не понятные сиволы при ререзвном копирование схемы postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

При резервном копировании схемы postgres, через dbeaver появляются какие то символы. Не могу понять, как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: делаю бэкап схемы БД с помощью Dbeaver, при бэкапе получаю sql фаил в таком виде.

Comment: судя по характерной метке PGDMP - вы сделали pg_dump формата custom, но пытаетесь его открыть текстовым редактором вместо использования pg_restore. Исправьте или формат дампа или используйте pg_restore

Comment: @Мелкий Спасибо! теперь всё ок!